# On Google Cloud SQL, how can I move a Project ID to another Project Name?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

We currently enrolled to Google Cloud SQL. Our current problem is that we have two apps engine running and we would like to move a Project ID to another project name which has Cloud SQL enabled. what we have right now is We have one project ID who is just connected to a different Project Name. We want to move it permanently and delete the Project Name that it is currently in.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the project ID on a Google Cloud Console Project.

If you can afford to shut down your database access for a while, an easy way to move your database from one project to another is to export all your data from your current Cloud SQL instance to a Cloud Storage bucket, and then import it to a new similar Cloud SQL instance on the other project.